# Configure WCF service to accept unqualified parameter

Tags: wcf, web-services

My WCF service does not recognize request parameter values that are sent in unqualified form and substitutes default values instead.

For example, this request will yield a result of "You entered: 21".

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sam="http://www.example.org/SampleService/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sam:GetData>
         <sam:value>21</sam:value>
      </sam:GetData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But the response to this request is "You entered: 0".

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sam="http://www.example.org/SampleService/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sam:GetData>
         <value>21</value>
      </sam:GetData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**How can I modify my service so that both types of requests will use the value I send in?**

*IService1.cs*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfServiceLibrary2
{
    // NOTE: If you change the interface name "IService1" here, you must also update the reference to "IService1" in App.config.
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.example.org/SampleService/", Name = "sampleservice")]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }

    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

*Service1.cs*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfServiceLibrary2
{
   public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two requests are **not** equivalent XML and don't conform to the service WSDL. The "unqualified" request will parse the `value` element into the default XML namespace which will depend on the overall XML for that request. WCF doesn't understand `value` as being part of the soap envelop XML and can't match it to any DataContract class. You can try making the default XML namespace be your service XML namespace as shown below and see if the service will then process it correctly:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns="http://www.example.org/SampleService/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <GetData>
         <value>21</value>
      </GetData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: You are right, that will work, but I'm looking for ways I can modify the service instead of the request. I apologize for any lack of clarity and will edit my question appropriately. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, but you cannot configure a WCF service to do what you want. The only way the "unqualified" soap request would work as you defined it is to have the client generate a soap Envelope element that has both the "sam" alias and the default XML namespace set to your service XML namespace.

Comment: I do not know if this is possible with WCF services, but the limitation you mention is not applicable to web services in general. The "attributeFormDefault" attribute of the "xs:schema" tag and the "form" attribute of the "xs:element" tag can be set in the wsdl/xsd's to accept unqualified elements. And I'm working on migrating a service that does just that. But since I'm using a code-first approach, I'm guessing I need to modify my service contract .cs file to generate a WSDL with the right settings.

Comment: By that last comment I didn't mean to say you are incorrect about whether WCF supports my desired functionality. I just wasn't sure if you were speaking from a general point. If it's indeed not possible, some documentation would be very helpful. Thank you again for your time thus far!

Comment: Good luck on your search. The simplest test is to generate a WSDL with an XSD configured to support what you want and then use the command line SvcUtil utility to generate the .NET proxy code. Next, check the generated DataContract classes to see how that element is serialized into code. If you get an error or an unusable class structure then you have your answer. :)

Comment: The suggestion to examine the generated code was an excellent one, and it seems that WCF is indeed not going  to do exactly what I want here. Client-side workarounds include changing client requests to qualify their elements with namespace prefixes or having them supply a default namespace in their request. Alternatively, some parameters could be put in an "empty string" namespace on the service side, but that would break clients using the other namespace.