# WCF Namespace issues

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, wcf

I'm trying to replicate a web service, had a fair deal of issue so far, but this one is giving my some extra grief.

The existing application that'll consume my service can not be changed, but since I can sniff the data it sends, I have a fairly good idea what the problem is.

My problem is that the existing web service have removed the namespace on parameters, causing my service the recieve Nothing on each parameter.

My service gets a"urn:" on the Parameter tag:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:SOAPEWebIntf-ISOAPEWeb2">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:GetTestList>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:TestGroupID>1024</urn:TestGroupID>
      </urn:GetTestList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The existing application sends this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:SOAPEWebIntf-ISOAPEWeb2">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:GetTestList>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <TestGroupID>1024<TestGroupID>
      </urn:GetTestList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Any idea how I can get rid of the urn: in the parameter tag, **WIHTOUT removing it from the `<urn:GetTestList>` tag**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be done.

You can set the namespace at the service level (using the `ServiceContract` attribute), and you can also namespace the values *within a complex parameter* (using the `DataContract` attribute).

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas...." xmlns:hi="hello">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <hi:MyOperation>
         <hi:MyComplexParameter>
             <Property1></Property1>
         </hel:data>
         ....
```

I played around with implementing `ISeralizable`, but it is of course only valid for 'complex' types - i.e. you can serialize your object however you want, buy you can't serialize an `int` outside of how .NET wants you to serialize. And even if you do serialize your object differently you are only able to namespace the things inside the object, not the object itself.

Finally I went to google and found this: [Configure WCF service to accept unqualified parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944602/configure-wcf-service-to-accept-unqualified-parameter)

If you absolutely need to do this you would probably implement something that catches the WCF message before deserialization and handles this issue. That sounds pretty painful.